# mod_rewrite misbehaves if regex matches existing file, but only in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an `.htaccess` rule like this:

```
RewriteRule    ^z/([^/]+)$    y.html?$1    [NC,L]
```

This rule works fine.  But if I change the rule slightly, to:

```
RewriteRule    ^y/([^/]+)$    y.html?$1    [NC,L]
```

When I try to load `y/anything` I get a 404 and the following message in the error log:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/y.html/anything
```

The only difference I can see is that `z.html` does not exist, but `y.html` does.  At first I thought maybe the initial transform was triggering a recursive re-write, but I don't see how this could be.  It should rewrite:

```
`y/anything`
```

to

```
`y.html?anything`
```

Which does NOT have a slash in it.  In fact, the only problem with the re-written URL is that it has a slash where I specified a question mark.  What is going on here?

It gets stranger. If I change the rewrite URL, e.g. to

```
RewriteRule    ^y/([^/]+)$    /q.html?$1    [NC,L]
```

it STILL is telling me `/var/www/y.html/anything` not found, not q.html..

If I move `y.html` to `y.js` on the server, then it tells me `/var/www/y.js/anything` is not found.  It really seems like it is somehow matching `/dir/` and changing it to an existing file.  Is there a default rule somewhere in apache that might do this?

I tried a hard reload in the browser, which had no effect.

Update: I tried to use `RewriteLog` to see what was going on with the re-writing.  However, to do this I had move my rewrite entries to the `VirtualHost` section of my main config.  After I did this the pattern matching completely stopped until I changed my rule to:

```
RewriteRule    ^/y/([^/]+)$    /y.html?$1    [NC,L]
```

After making this change, everything works as expected.  So why can't I get it to work in the .htaccess file?  Neither regex works properly there (with or without the leading slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this problem in the future, the issue I was having was that MultiViews was interfering with my URL resolution.  When I removed "MultiViews" from the list of options for the `<Location/>` in the `<VirtualHost>` the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Having the following in the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On                                                           
RewriteRule    ^z/([^/]+)$    /y.html?$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^y/([^/]+)$    /y.html?$1    [NC,L]
```

will show the contents of `y.html`

You might want to do a hard refresh of the page because if it was previously redirected to `/y.html/anything`, but then changed to `/y.html?anything` it might still be in a cache on your browser. Double check with your other browsers that the same thing is happening on them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. To clarify though, I only have one or the other of the re-write rules at once.  I changed it from `y` to `z` initially as part of experimenting to get something to work.

Comment: Nope that didn't fix it.  And then things got weirder... (updated question)

Comment: what is in your full htaccess file?

Comment: The first and either second or third line that you provided.  I have also tried with and without the leading slash in both the regex and the rewritten URL.

Comment: Here is another perhaps important clue... if I change the rewrite URL, e.g. to `RewriteRule    ^y/([^/]+)$    /q.html?$1    [NC,L]` it STILL is telling me `/var/www/y.html/anything` not found, *not* q.html...

Comment: That sounds to me that it is being cached. Try something different after `y/` and on a different browser.

Comment: Nope.  I think there is some default rule somewhere... if I do `/dir/` for any directory that does not exist but for which there is an existing `dir.ext` for any ext, the error log says `/dir.ext/` is not found.

Comment: Is there any settings in your control panel that might have an effect/any other htaccess or config files?