# apache appending extension to failing directory requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to debug a different problem on my server and have found a strange behavior that I am trying to get to the bottom of.  Presumably there is a configuration entry somewhere for it, but I can't seem to find it.

If I request any URL of the form:

```
https://localhost/somedirname/
```

and if `somedirname` does not exist, but there exists any file in the directory starting with that name and any arbitrary extention `ext`, I get an error:

```
`The requested URL /somedirname.ext/ was not found on this server.`
```

This appears to be [causing other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725584/mod-rewrite-misbehaves-if-regex-matches-existing-file-but-only-in-htaccess-fil).  If I look at my error log, it says :

```
File does not exist: /var/www/somedirname.ext/
```

But in my access log it says:

```
"GET /somedirname/ HTTP/1.1" 404 204
```

For the purpose of the test there are no rewriting rules present, and no ErrorDocument, and rewriting is not even turned on.  So what could be causing this?

If it makes any difference, this is the nearly stock Apache running under Mac OS X.  I have tried three different boxes, one running OS X 10.9.2, one running 10.8.5 and one running 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple.  When I removed "MultiViews" from the list of options for the `<Location/>` in the `<VirtualHost>` the issue went away.